# Simple OSM Raw Query Filter

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, quickosm

I have a simple raw OSM query that I am using in QGIS model designer (Build Raw Query):

```
    [out:xml] [timeout:25];
(
    node["highway"]( {{bbox}});
    node["building"]( {{bbox}});
    way["highway"]( {{bbox}});
    way["building"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["highway"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["building"]( {{bbox}});
);
(._;>;);
out body;
```

It works good, but I I only want the building polygons and roads, but I also get these "OSMQuery Points" (Seen in red below).

Can I add a line to the code to filter the "OSMQuery Points" out?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified how do you launch the query, from the QuickOSM UI or from Processing? Are you in Processing model?

You can :

- Remove your two lines asking for points in your query. But you might still have some points having another tag on a node belonging to a way or relation
- If running in the UI, remove the "Points" layer output geometry. It's in the "Advanced" section. This can be saved in your QuickOSM preset.
  *If running from Processing, you can choose which layer to display