# Filter out point layer from Quick OSM using raw query

Tags: qgis, query, quickosm

I want to be able to create an OSM Query for 'highways' and 'buildings' only (no OSMQuery Points) in the Model Designer, so I need to be able to understand all of the code required to create an OSM query.  In the Quick OSM Plugin, this is fairly easy with to do in the UI and it even will show you the raw query; However, to remove the Points, you need to uncheck 'Points' in the Outputs section, but unfortunately this does not translate back into the provided raw query code, so I can't see what is being done to filter out the points.  What code do I need to add to remove the OSMQuery Points?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you just care about the end result (rather than how you get to it), you could consider adding a step to the Model to remove the OSMPoints layer

Comment: @Tom Brennan, I like your idea about adding a step to the Model to remove the OSMPoints layer.  Can anyone point me in the right direction of a processing tool that would remove the OSMPoints layer?

Comment: See below for model to only load required layer(s). Is this question different from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/471205/simple-osm-raw-query-filter - or should they be merged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a model using the approach outlined at https://docs.3liz.org/QuickOSM/user-guide/processing/

**Input:**

- Extent

**Steps:**

- Build raw (OSM) query (under **QuickOSM->Advanced**)
- Download file (under **File tools**)
- String concatenation (under **Modeler tools**)
- Convert format (under **GDAL**)

**Output:**

- Single type of geometry

By adding multiple **String concatenation** steps, you can extract the various types that you want, while excluding those you don't eg Points.

[image]

Detail for **Build raw query** is as per the question:

[image]

For **String concatenation**, the second input is `|layername=<layer type>`.

[image]

As per the link above, the filters you can use in the **String concatenation** step are:

- `|layername=points`
- `|layername=lines`
- `|layername=multilinestrings`
- `|layername=multipolygons`

Comment: that is an awesome explaination.  Thank you for taking the time to help explain it to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a QuickOSM query for Brighton.

```
[out:xml] [timeout:25];
 {{geocodeArea:brighton}} -> .area_0;
(
    node["highway"](area.area_0);
    way["highway"](area.area_0);
    relation["highway"](area.area_0);
);
(._;>;);
out body;
```

[image]

Note the 'points' shown on screen are nodes for start/end topology.

Comment: Thank for the answer, but those 'points' are what I am trying to elimate via the query code